# Don't know which version of node I am runnig

Tags: 16.04, nodejs

I need to run a node script that requires a node version greater than 4.3.0. When I try to run the script something goes wrong, i.e. part of the output:

```
WARN engine enhanced-resolve@3.1.0: wanted: {"node":">=4.3.0 <5.0.0 || >=5.10"} (current: {"node":"4.2.6","npm":"3.5.2"})
WARN engine loader-runner@2.3.0: wanted: {"node":">=4.3.0 <5.0.0 || >=5.10"} (current: {"node":"4.2.6","npm":"3npm WARN lifecycle utf-8-validate@3.0.1~install: cannot run in wd %s %s (wd=%s) utf-8-validate@3.0.1 prebuild-install || node-gyp rebuild /home/diego/work/creditgate24/kloten-tegel/tegel/tegel/node_modules/utf-8-validate
```

I thus checked the current version:

```
$node -v
v4.2.6
```

but if I run:

```
$nvm ls
         v7.4.0
->       system
node -> stable (-> v7.4.0) (default)
stable -> 7.4 (-> v7.4.0) (default)
iojs -> iojs- (-> N/A) (default)
```

I am new to node and nvm. Which version I am actually running? If 4.2.6 how could I upgrade it? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current version is v2.4.6.

Here are the steps to upgrade via npm:

1. Clean Cache Fully

   username@pcname:~$ sudo npm cache clean -f

   npm WARN using --force I sure hope you know what you are doing.
2. Install n Module

   ```
   username@pcname:~$ sudo npm install -g n 

   /usr/local/bin/n -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/n/bin/n
   n@2.0.2 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/n
   ```
3. Install Latest Release of Node

   ```
   username@pcname:~$ sudo n stable 

    install : node-v6.0.0
      mkdir : /usr/local/n/versions/node/6.0.0
      fetch : https://nodejs.org/dist/v6.0.0/node-v6.0.0-linux-x64.tar.gz
   ############################################################ 100.0%
   installed : v6.0.0
   ```
4. Setup Binary Link – Now link your node binary with latest node installed binary file using following command.

   ```
   username@pcname:~$ sudo ln -sf /usr/local/n/versions/node/6.0.0/bin/node /usr/bin/node
   ```
5. Check your version of node - Should be latest version.

   ```
   username@pcname:~$ node -v 

   v6.0.0
   ```

You should now be able to run your script.